# GitHub Pull Request showing some commits from master

Tags: git, github, version-control, pull-request

I currently have an open pull request. I first made one commit, and then the repo owner requested changes on it, then I pushed a second commit.

But when pushing the second commit, the project master branch kept updating, so I decided to make a rebase to my pull request branch.

Now my pull request shows my first commit, then other commits from other people from the repo master branch and then my second commit.

The question is: how can I remove those commits from the master branch and leave only the two commits I made?

Thank you.

Comment: If this is a public repository, can you include a link to the repo and to your pull request? The behavior you're seeing typically means that your local master branch wasn't in sync with the remote master branch when you rebased, but it could be something else.

Comment: https://github.com/WhisperSystems/Signal-Android/pull/6756

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your problem is that your pull request appears to include a merge commit.  That's not something you generally want in a PR, which should typically be a linear set of changes on top of the target branch (usually `master`).  The merge is bringing in additional commits.

Looking at your PR, I see the following commits that appear to be the ones you intend to submit:

```
42a310e fercarcedo@gmail.com Merge branch 'autodarkmodeambient' of https://github.com/fercarcedo/Signal-Android into autodarkmodeambient
1678038 fercarcedo@gmail.com Refactored automatic dark mode and solved possible memory leaks
a8ba129 fercarcedo@gmail.com Fixed race condition, memory leak and improvements
b194a83 fercarcedo@gmail.com Automatic dark mode based on ambient light
```

If you drop the merge commit...

```
git reset 1678038
```

...and then resubmit the pull request:

```
git push -f
```

You'll end up with a cleaner submission.  You can see what it would look like here:

- https://github.com/WhisperSystems/Signal-Android/compare/master...larsks:pull/6756?expand=1

The lesson here is "don't merge things into your feature branch".

Comment: Separate from this problem is that your patches are against 4.8.0, and won't apply against current `master`.  It's possible the project may ask you to rebase your changes so that they apply against the current version.